# How to make three select boxes in-line with bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have three select box horizontally for date of birth three select are like this
`Month` - `Day` -  `Year`So I am finding a way these should be responsive. Is there any bootstrap class which can help me out?
I am using `form-control` but it take `100%` width of container.

```js
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">Pet's Date of Birth:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">       
          <select id="dob_month" class="form-control col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" name="dob_month">
      <?= $dob_month; ?>
       </select>
       <select id="dob_day" class="form-control" name="dob_day" >
        <?= $dob_day; ?>
         </select>
     <select id="dob_year" class="form-control" name="dob_year">
        <?= $dob_year; ?>
     </select>     
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you put the code you tried in fiddle?

Comment: @Vim code is in php I have updated my question please check.

Comment: Have you tried adding a form-horizontal to that first div?. Also, this may help: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multiple-control-input-group

Comment: @LeonelAtencio this is not my question related answer please read my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have better success placing your form elements into `col-*-*` decorated DIVs:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">Pet's Date of Birth:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">      
      <div class="row"> <!-- added div.row -->
        <div class="col-xs-4"> <!-- added div.col-xs-4 -->
          <select id="dob_month" class="form-control" name="dob_month">
            <?= $dob_month; ?>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"> <!-- added div.col-xs-4 -->
          <select id="dob_day" class="form-control" name="dob_day" >
            <?= $dob_day; ?>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"> <!-- added div.col-xs-4 -->
          <select id="dob_year" class="form-control" name="dob_year">
            <?= $dob_year; ?>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

In this case you basically want three columns, so I have added a `row` element inside the `col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12` DIV and dropped the form elements into `col-xs-4` DIVs to lay these out into three columns.

Comment: Hi Kevin. Would you include an introductory sentence or two about your strategy here? I am sure this solves the OP's problem very well, but other readers who wish to learn from it may benefit from some explanation (I think code-only answers are somewhat discouraged on Stack Overflow, for this reason).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group connected-group">
  <label class="control-label">
    Date of Birth <span class="symbol required"></span>
  </label>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      <select name="dd" id="dd" class="form-control">
        <option value="">DD</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      <select name="mm" id="mm" class="form-control">
        <option value="">MM</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
      <select name="mm" id="mm" class="form-control">
        <option value="">YYYY</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not necessary to specify `col-sm-3` and `col-md-3` ... `col-xs-3` would suffice. (But I think he wants `col-xs-4` to make three columns out of the twelve.)

Comment: Yes @Kevin you are right. Actually,  it my first time answering on mobile app and it was very hard to code here. So, I thing I made a mistake.

Comment: @aman: as per my note to Kevin, would you preface this answer with a sentence or two on what your solution does? Without some context, code-only answers are a bit hard to follow for readers other than the original poster. Thanks!